# HTML tags in Content

Tags: asp.net

I'm implementing full text search on a table named as `tbljobs` on the cloumn named as `jobdescription`. In front end I'm getting html tags in the description. I'm showing the records in `GridView` and on `Gridview`'s `RowDataBound` enent I'm decoding the text. I'm using the following code on `Gridview`'s `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridNewlyPostedJobs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
 string decodedText =      HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblJobDescription")).Text);
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblJobDescription")).Text = decodedText;
         }
    }
```

But nothing works..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataRowView` to get the Data...

```
protected void GridNewlyPostedJobs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; 
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
   {  
     string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rowView["jobdescription"]);             
     ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblJobDescription")).Text = decodedText;         
   }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but sorry to say that i allready did that but forget to post .